# setting up a catch to only recycle the bitmap if loaded

Tags: android, button, asynchronous, bitmap, android-asynctask

I have this problem i would like to recycle the image only if it loaded if it hasnt finish loaded and the user navigates away from it then i shouldnt recycle the bitmap because it doesnt exist and the system crashes on me,

```
Button bRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
    bRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("intent"));
            bitmaptwo.recycle();
            finish();


        }
        });
```

am doing this to stop a memory leak and it works but is not the best way of implementing it since when the image hasnt loaded the system crashes because it is an asynchronimous task, can someone help me?,
thank you

Comment: Could you please give us your crash log?

Comment: the crash log says Android RunTime Fatal Exeption : main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(bitmaptwo != null){
    bitmaptwo.recycle();
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for the anwser i was wondering and sory if i didnt understand am new at programing but i want the image to recycle only when is loaded and not when is not loaded, can you explain a lil further?

Comment: If the image hasn't loaded `bitmaptwo` will be null and hence you are getting NullPointerException when trying to call recycle. FYI you should be doing this in onStop() of your activity and not in the click listener of some button starting another activity.

Comment: i see thank you very much am gonna try it right now :) ill be right back

Comment: thank you so much it works for my exeption for some reason it creates a memory leake if the exeption happens but am not counting on that exeption being the norm i just wanted to avoid the error, thank you so much :) i really apreciate it